# How to identify A/A* Journal

Tags: journals, ranking, australia, bibliometrics

The academic promotions procedure at my Australian university includes specifically publications in A/A* journals. What defines A/A* and where can I find out which journals are in this category?

Comment: http://www.core.edu.au/conference-portal

Comment: Any official promotion criteria should be explicitly spelled out by your university.  Only will know the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at CORE if you're in computer science, like a commenter mentioned: [conferences](http://portal.core.edu.au/conf-ranks), [journals](http://portal.core.edu.au/jnl-ranks).

There's also the ERA outlet ranking lists (unofficial website): [conferences](http://lamp.infosys.deakin.edu.au/era/?page=cmain), [journals](http://lamp.infosys.deakin.edu.au/era/?page=jmain), but it is old.

Though you're best asking your institution as to where they are getting the rankings from.

Answer (score -1):

A and A* labels on journals are obsolete.  The current custom is to refer to impact factor.  Consult your head of school.

Comment: Impact factor doesn't mean much in some fields, such as mathematics.

Comment: Could you add a reference or indicate your experience to add to the credibility of the answer?

Comment: @TommiBrander No, I never do that on stack exchange.